# Как проверить длину текста,и если букв в тексте больше определенного количества то скрыть часть из них?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Хочу сделать так:
Если у пользователя в имени и фамилии больше 20 букв, то лишнюю часть скрыть.

```js
$text_length = $('.test_name').text().length;
if($text_length > 20){
// Хотелось бы чтобы лишние символы были скрыты
  $('.test_name').text('...');
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h5 class="test_name">John Doe</h5>
<h5 class="test_name">Andrew Ivanov</h5>
<h5 class="test_name">Alexander Maslennikov</h5>
<h5 class="test_name">Christopher Robinson</h5>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Бесплатно, без смс, javascript и jquery:

```css
.test_name {
  width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<h5 class="test_name">John Doe</h5>
<h5 class="test_name">Andrew Ivanov</h5>
<h5 class="test_name">Alexander Maslennikov</h5>
<h5 class="test_name">Christopher Robinson</h5>
```